# Cast MenuItem to the bound object

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I have a SubMenu in a ContextMenu which ItemSource is set to a expression like

```
ContextMenu.Items[i].ItemsSource = DatabaseInstance.GetAllObjects()
```

When i handle the clicks from the ContextMenu i have this event handler:
XALM:

```
<ContextMenu MenuItem.Click="ContextMenu_Click">
```

C#:

```
        if (e.OriginalSource as MyObject == null) {
            //Not MyObject. Choose action by comparing Header
        }
        else {
            // The clicked item is a MyObject, send to another method
        }
```

But even though the OriginalSource was created by an object of the type MyObject i always get is as a null.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the MenuItem instance in the handler and check the DataContext

```
if(((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext is MyObject)
{
     // The clicked item is a MyObject, send to another method
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Though i had to use e.OriginalSource instead of sender